# How to format GMT time with strftime in Python

Tags: python

I want to add 2 hours to the current GMTime.

```
gmt_time = time.gmtime()

gmt_time_to_dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(gmt_time))
print(gmt_time_to_dt)

gmt_plus = gmt_time_to_dt + datetime.timedelta(minutes = 120)
print(gmt_plus)
```

Which this code does, but I need to have it in this format:

```
'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'
```

How to do this?

Comment: So what's the Z for?

Comment: I think you've got a typo here, you should probably review my answer regarding it.

Comment: The "Z" is for Zulu Time IIRC

Comment: I learn something new every day: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strftime(gmt_plus, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

or:

```
gmt_plus.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

Comment: I get ... TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str' Do I need to convert it back to a datetime obj?

Comment: @NickJD from your example it gmt_plus is a datetime object. did anything change?

Comment: @NickJD printing `gmt_plus.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')` still gives you the same error?

Comment: gmt_plus.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ') works perfectly. Thanks heaps!

Comment: @NickJD great! if I answered your question can you please accept my answer?

Comment: Done. Cheers all for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Imports first:

```
import datetime
import time
from time import mktime
import pytz
```

Try this:

```
gmt_time = time.gmtime()

gmt_time_to_dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(gmt_time))
print(gmt_time_to_dt)

gmt_plus = gmt_time_to_dt + datetime.timedelta(minutes = 120)
print(gmt_plus.isoformat())
```

prints:

```
2014-08-21T05:57:06
```

Although I think you might mean this:

```
gmt_time = time.gmtime()

gmt_time_to_dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(gmt_time), 
                                                 tz=pytz.timezone('GMT'))

gmt_plus = gmt_time_to_dt + datetime.timedelta(minutes = 120)
print(gmt_plus.isoformat())
```

prints:

```
2014-08-21T10:09:56+00:00
```

If you really want to specify the format, I think you've got a typo:

```
gmt_plus.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z')
```

prints:

```
'2014-08-21T10:09:56GMT'
```

Comment: For me gmt_plus.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z') prints: 2014-08-21T05:12:16Z

Comment: @NickJD did you do this: `gmt_time_to_dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(gmt_time),
 tz=pytz.timezone('GMT'))`